# Question on modifying shell initialization files to color root's prompt red during "su"

Tags: linux, bash, root, prompt, bashrc

I am in the midst of learning Linux, specifically the BASH Shell. I have been trying to edit the initialization files so that whenever I su into root, my prompt will turn red. I am using the code posted below. I am placing the code into the .bashrc file, but have also tried /etc/profile and .bash_profile. If I manually source the files my prompt will turn red for root only like I want, however, if I issue su without sourcing my prompt remains unchanged?

```bsh
if [ $EUID -eq 0 ]; then
        PS1='\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m' 
else
        PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ ' 
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` usually doesn't load the new user's profile scripts by default. Use [`su -l`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html#OPTIONS) to solve this.

Comment: Is there another configuration file in which su reads that I could just add ```source /etc/profile```

Comment: My workaround for this is to set `alias su='su -l'` in my user's profile (e. g. `~/.bash_aliases`).

Comment: I actually figured out the ultimate issue. I was in the wrong directory. Using ```su``` to change to root still left me in the /home/user directory. I needed to create a .bashrc in the /root directory